# Hide derived .js and .js.map from tsx files in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, csproj

In VS Code you can do something like this:

```
{
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/*.js.map": {"when": "$(basename).js"},
        "**/*.js": {"when": "$(basename).ts"},
        "**/**/*.js": {"when": "$(basename).tsx"}
    }
}
```

to hide `*.js.map` files when a equivalent `*.js` file exists and hide any `*.js` files when an equivalent `*.ts` or `*.tsx` file exists.

It seems by default that `*.js.map` files are nested under `*.js` files and `*.js` files are nested under `*.ts` files but not under `*.tsx` files.

I was trying to replicate this using MSBuild in the `csproj` but I am not having a lot of luck, I have tried:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="**/*.js" Condition="Exists('$(RootDir)$(RecursiveDir)\$(FileName).tsx)')" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Is there a way to get VS to hide the `*.js` and `*.js.map` files that are generated from `*.tsx` files?

Comment: How did you solve this issue please? I have a some problem.

Comment: I kind of cheated by not writing the out as part of the build process. Using webpack and its related `ts-loader` the compiled `.js` is written into memory instead of the disk.

Comment: Please, can you share this workaround? That will be very helpful to me. Configuration of TsConfig and webpack config? Feel free put as an answer.

Comment: @Jenan I have shared the workaround as an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45235841/580626

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments I have found a way around this, so not quite answering the question. I have configured my build tool (webpack) to compile typescript files without producing an intermediary output (i.e. .js or .jsx)

I have an [example repo](https://github.com/Meberem/typescript-webpack-test/tree/8709df9bffc4d1c900d81b918312932a9c3b7d1f) demonstrating how this can be achieved.

Comment: I've found a issue, if you need produce a source map for debugging, that is will not be working, who do you think about automatic generation source map?

Comment: Webpack has a some options for this: https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/#using-source-maps

Comment: Yes, but is necessary that will be source map generated for every file or this is property for finaly bundle and input files are only tsx files?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished via msbuild definitions, though I had trouble because the project system tries remove/add those definitions. However, putting this inside a `Directory.Build.targets` file next to or in the directory hierarchy above your project should accomplish what you want:

```
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
    <_TsxFile Include="**\*.tsx" />
    <Content Update="@(_TsxFile->'%(RelativeDir)%(Filename).js')" DependentUpon="%(Filename).tsx" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Produces this result in VS:

[image]

Comment: I have added a `Directory.Build.targets` in different places in the directory but my Visual Studio doesn't seem to hide the files. I have since been able to change the build process so that `*.js` files aren't generated anymore but it would still be interesting to find out how to nest them correctly. Thanks for your answer

Comment: You probably need to close the solution (maybe even VS) and open it again for the d.b.targets to be picked up.. vs does heavy caching of imported files (even modifications).
I do consider this a bug in the VS typescript SDK though, you could report it via connect / send feedback.

Comment: Please, can you specify a location where can I find Directory.Build.targets?